# MVC2 validates model also there are no validation attributes to properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a model:

```
public class OverdraftForm
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }

    public OverdraftType Type { get; set; }

    public decimal PermanentAmount { get; set; }
    public int ExpirationPeriod { get; set; }

    public decimal OnetimeAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public CreditType CreditType { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And my action is

```
public ActionResult CreateOverdraft(OverdraftForm form)
{
    if (form.Type == OverdraftType.Permanent)
        return CreatePermanentOverdraft(form);
    return CreateOnetimeOverdraft(form);
}
```

The point is when I debug it, even on the first line of action ModelState.IsValid is false, and it says that OnetimeAmount should have a value. I'm using MVC2, I guess some changes to it cause this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the Required attribute on the field to false. by default it is true.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question. But how should I do that? [Required(false)] does not (and should not) work

Comment: try to make it nullable:
public decimal? OnetimeAmount { get; set; }

Answer (score 3):

It is a change with MVC2 - [on automatic databinding, it's going to read all your properties (even the read-only ones) to try to validate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211829/why-does-asp-net-mvc-care-about-my-read-only-properties-during-databinding).